# Is having a top nav and a left nav a good thing?

Tags: navigation

Look at http://www.gainsco.com.  They have a top nav and a left nav.  The top and left nav take you to the same places.  To me, this is redundant, confusing and unnecessary.  Is there a good reason to setup this design?

(Update, actually the menu is almost identical on the bottom nav in sub pages too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of no good reason to do this.

The left nav shows child pages, which is good. But the top nav is totally redundant; it could be removed and replaced with something more interesting for the brand. Or the left nav could only show the child navigation for the section that the user is in.

The bottom nav is another question... I don't mind having main navigation items replicated at the bottom of each page, along with all the privacy policies and whatnot, though I don't think it's necessary. In fact, their implementation of the nav replication threw me off a little, since it actually repeats the whole thing twice: once to show the child pages and again below that.